# Most efficient Java data structure to frequently find values in 3-dimensions?

Tags: java, android, performance

I've never worked with 3 dimensional data until now, I'm trying to implement a structure which allows me to store objects in positions relative to each other in a structure which allows me to find the coordinates (x,y,z) of any given object, to find any objects adjacent to it and to get a list of all values (rooms).

The data will be read frequently but changed infrequently and I'm targetting Android so memory efficiency is important. Currently the bounds for all 3 axis are 0-11 but in the future it must scale for axis 0-250 (so 250^3).

Below is my current code, I've read a lot of related questions but not found a definitive answer. Is there a better data structure / way to do this in java?

```
public class Building {

    private int mStartX;
    private int mStartZ;
    private Bounds mBounds;
    private Map<XYPair, Map<Integer, Room>> mRooms;

    public Building(Bounds b) {
        mBounds = b;
        mRooms = new HashMap<>();
        mStartX = Math.round(b.getMaxWidth() / 2f) -1;
        mStartZ = Math.round(b.getMaxHeight() / 2f) -1;
        Map<Integer, Room> zMap = new HashMap<>();
        zMap.put(mStartZ, new StartRoom());
        mRooms.put(new XYPair(mStartX, 0), zMap);
    }

    public Room roomAt(int x, int y, int z) {
        Room room = null;
        Map<Integer, Room> zMap = mRooms.get(new XYPair(x, y));
        if (zMap != null) {
            room = zMap.get(z);
        }
        return room;
    }

    //FIXME: There must me a more efficient structure
    public List<Room> getAdjacentRooms(Room l) {
        List<Room> adjacent = null;
        if (l != null) {
            for (int y = 0; y < mBounds.getMaxLength(); y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < mBounds.getMaxWidth(); x++) {
                    for (int z = 0; z < mBounds.getMaxHeight(); z++) {
                        if (l.equals(roomAt(x, y, z))) {
                            adjacent = getAdjacentRooms(x, y, z);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return adjacent;
    }

    public List<Room> getAdjacentRooms(int x, int y, int z) {
        List<Room> adjacent = new ArrayList<>();
        if (x > 0) {
            Room room = roomAt(x-1, y, z);
            if (room != null) {
                adjacent.add(room);
            }
        }
        if (x < mBounds.getMaxWidth()) {
            Room room = roomAt(x+1, y, z);
            if (room != null) {
                adjacent.add(room);
            }
        }
        if (y > 0) {
            Room room = roomAt(x, y-1, z);
            if (room != null) {
                adjacent.add(room);
            }
        }
        if (y < mBounds.getMaxLength()) {
            Room room = roomAt(x, y+1, z);
            if (room != null) {
                adjacent.add(room);
            }
        }
        if (z > 0) {
            Room room = roomAt(x, y, z-1);
            if (room != null) {
                adjacent.add(room);
            }
        }
        if (z < mBounds.getMaxHeight()) {
            Room room = roomAt(x, y, z+1);
            if (room != null) {
                adjacent.add(room);
            }
        }
        return adjacent;
    }

    public List<Room> getAllRooms() {
        List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map<Integer, Room> zMap : mRooms.values()) {
            rooms.addAll( zMap.values() );   
        }
        return rooms;
    }

    private final class XYPair {

        private final int mX, mY;

        public XYPair(int x, int y) {
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return mX;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return mY;
        }

        public int hashCode() {
            return (mX * 31) ^ mY;
        }

        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (o instanceof XYPair) {
                XYPair other = (XYPair) o;
                return (mX == other.getX() && mY == other.getY());
            }
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How sparse/dense is your data?  If it's relatively sparse, a `Map` would be a time- and space-efficient way of storing the data.  For instance, key each `Room` by `XYZCoordinate`.  And also have each `Room` remember its currently assigned coordinate, so that you don't have to run an exhaustive search through the entire data-structure to determine the x/y/z coordinate of a given room.  The `getAdjacentRooms(Room l)` method is the main inefficiency in your code, time-wise, because it searches the entire array for something that should be attainable by doing `room.getCoords()`.

Comment: since it's write seldom, read often. then why not append the adjacent rooms everytime you add a room ? and store them in say "SortedMap<Room> adjacentRooms; " with the comparator sorted by x,y,z.

Comment: Aroth having the Room remember it's coords occurred to me too but seemed like a hack, although at the moment it's seeming like the best option, eventually the entire 11^3 grid should be filled. Angel, I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: @NickCardoso I agree with aroth, each room should remember its own coordinates. It's not a hack; the hack is that the coordinates (a property of the room) are stored outside of the room, implicit in the data structure). That might be a valid hack if you're low on memory, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I'd also suggest you normalise your data structure somewhat - the z-ordinate is second-class for no reason I can see. Either a map in a map in a map, or the slightly more sane approach of changing XYPair to XYZCoordinate, and having a single map. It would not change your access patterns at all, and the exact same key into the map (the XYZCoordinate) could also be stored in the Room structure.

Comment: Thanks Logan, I think you're right about those changes for . I've already added the coords onto the room object, I still think of coords as something relevant to the building / big picture rather than the rooms. Although it has them now, the room doesn't need it's own coordinate for any reason.

Comment: If one of you wants to write up an answer from these comments I can close the question